# How to return a mapped string from a Service that fetches values from an API with rjxs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a service called `MappingService` in Angular 7. This service fetches a list of names from an API:

```
{
  'guid1': 'Item 1',
  'guid2': 'Item 2',
  'guide': 'Item 3',
}
```

These values should later be mapped by their ids. Of course I could subscribe to `items$` in a componentn and then do something like:

```
{{ mapping[id] }}
```

But I thought it would be nice, If I don't have to subscribe to that service or its list so I don't have to pass it around all the time, because the mapping is fixed once loaded and is needed by multiple components.

So I thought I add a method `map` to the service that does this:

- gets an id
- returns the corresponding string

Like:

```
{{ mappingSrervice.map(id) }}
```

But this is where I'm stuck:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MappingService {
  items$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.items$.pipe(mergeMap(items => {
      if (items) {
        return of(items);
      } else {
        return this.http.get<any>(
          'http://api'
        ).pipe(
          tap((response: any) => response),
          catchError(error => {
            return of([]);
          })
        );
      }
    }));
  }

  map(id: number): string {
    return this.items$[id] || null;
  }
}
```

How do I correctly implement `map()`? Should I run `getAll()` in the constructor? The problem is still of course that `items$` will not be filled before `getAll()` is finished.

Can I get it to work like I thought? Is `string` the correct return type?

I wonder whether this approach is possible? Or do I need to return promises instead? But this would generate a new level of abstraction, making it not that much simpler instead of the naive approach (just subscribing to `items$`.

Comment: That is not valid array that you are getting.

Comment: @AJT_82 True that. I tried to simplify it for the question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first talk about caching. You already tried using a `BehaviorSubject` which is a very good idea. As always with async operations, there is a certain timespan when the data is not available because it is still loading.
This is not a problem and we can deal with this in our components.
There is no really cool way to do the request before the application loads (there are ways but I don't want to recommend any of them).
Talking about this, a `BehaviorSubject` is not the best choice, because we always need to initialize it with a value.
What is more suitable is the `ReplaySubject`: It keeps the last elements in its buffer and replays them to each new subscriber.

While all this is cool the way you did it, we can do easier: with the `shareReplay()` operator.
This makes a cold observable hot, which means: It converts the normal HTTP Observable, which does an HTTP request for each subscriber, to a shared Observable which does its task once and shares its values with all subscribers.

The code could look something like this:

```
export class MappingService {

  items$ = this.getAll().pipe(shareReplay(1));


  getAll(): Observable<any>() {
    return this.http.get('http://api'); // also add catchError here as you already did
  }

}
```

For the very first subscriber, `getAll()` will be called and the HTTP request will be performed. For all subsequent subscribers, the cached value will be used.
Note that you still need to subscribe to the `items$` Observable, but it is not a problem or challenge to subscribe to Observables in components.

For the mapping I recommend using the RxJS `map()` operator.
You should provide a service method that takes an ID and returns an Observable with the result. It could look like this:

```
getItem(id: number): Observable<string> {
  return this.items$.pipe(
    map(items => items[id])
  );
}
```

This way – using Observables everywhere – you also avoid race conditions through async operations. Each of your Observables will return data as soon as they have arrived.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. Already upvoted. Today I learned a few new things. Will try everything out and get back to you. :)

Comment: I worked something out using your example. I have two small questions. I use it in my template like this: `{{ mappingService.getItem(id) | async }}`. Is this correct? And when I subscribe to `list$` in the component, like `this.mappingService.list$.subscribe(() => {});` I don't need to unsubscribe in `onDestroy()`, right?

Comment: For #1: Basically, that's correct. however, I'd recommend to keep the service instance private and not access it from the template. Instead, create properties in the component class that contain what you need, e.g. `item$ = this.mappingService.getItem();` – or as a method when you need params.

Comment: For #2: Yes and no. You always need to make sure the subscription will be terminated at some point to avoid memory leaks. For simple HTTP observables this is not necessary in most cases because HTTP always completes after the first emission. When you share the result with `shareReplay()` the completeg event will also be forwarded. So it always depends on your source. Since your source here is HTTP, you are fine and possibly dont need to unsubscribe!

Answer (score 1):

[Resolver](https://angular.jp/guide/router.en#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) may help you.

> In summary, you want to delay rendering the routed component until all necessary data have been fetched.

If you return `Observable` or `Promise` in the `resolve()` method of your resolver, your component is not rendered until the `Observable` completes or the `Promise` is fulfilled.
In your component you can access the data provided by the resolver with `route.snapshot.data.xxx`.

The drawback of this approach is that it delays the rendering of your component.
Actually, I believe that it would be better to simply subscribe to `items$` in this case.